# How to remove profile picture in Google account?

Tags: google-account, google-account-profile

I am looking for remove my profile picture and keep default Google account profile picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove/disassociate the photo on your Google Account Profile:

1. when you are signed into a Google service and click your avatar/photo in a Google service, click the Google + Profile link from the dropdown menu that appears.
2. Then click the "Edit Profile" button that appears.
3. In the popup window, rather than clicking the photo, click the "i" information icon (bottom right of attached screenshot).
   [image: information icon and link on edit google+ profile page]
4. On the "About Me" page that opens, click the edit icon at the right of the banner.
5. Now click the edit link on either photo.  At the bottom of the popup, you'll see a NO PHOTO button.
   [image: Google+ About Me No Photo Button]

Comment: How long does it take for this change to be reflected in my profile?

Comment: @Anson W Han: I cannot find the "No photo" button. Can you confirm this option is still available to you? Thank you!

Comment: @gncs Funny that the button was apparently there when I first clicked on the camera icon, but it didn't work. The second time I tried it, it disappeared... Google's such products are really a mess. Eh.

Comment: @gncs I figured out a way to do it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 17):

The solution in **2019**

1. Open the link https://aboutme.google.com/
2. Click on the picture
3. Click "No Photo" button

It will take up to 24 hours to get the picture removed from all Google products.

Comment: Still working in 2020. (Although your link redirects to https://myaccount.google.com/profile).

Comment: Awesome! It's working

Answer (score 3):

The method mentioned by Anson W Han seems to no longer work as the button has disappeared. But the following method worked for me:

1. Go to https://get.google.com/albumarchive/ to find all your albums stored on Google.
2. Go into the album called "Profile Photos"
3. Delete the profile photo that is currently in effect, or perhaps all of them (you may need to click on the photo and focus on it before you can find the delete option).
4. Your profile will now be displayed with just a character, as is the default.

Comment: This is the appropriate way if you want to delete the photo instead of just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to 'Personal Info' on the left hand menu
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page, click 'Go to About Me'
3. Click the little arrow on the right hand side in the profile picture box
4. There is the elusive remove pic option